# Node.js version changed, script no longer working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I believe I've gone from v0.10.31 to v.0.10.34 and since then, my node.js app is having problems.

```
/** Variables */
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
    url = require('url');

/** Listen on port # */
app.listen( 60003 );

/**
 * Parse server messages
 * Redirect to home page if accessed directly
 */
function handler( request, response ) {
    var requestURL = url.parse(request.url, true);

    /** ... */

    response.writeHead(302, {
        'Location': 'http://www.google.com'
    });
    response.end();
}
```

cat ./nohup.out

> ./node.js: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `(' ./node.js:
>   line 2:`var app = require('http').createServer(handler),'

Comment: Does running anything with node work by any chance?

Comment: Can you please issue `which node` and `node -v`? What OS are you running NodeJS, how have you installed and updated NodeJS?

Comment: The app seems to work by running `node node.js`  
  ---
`which node` returns '/usr/local/bin/node'  
`node -v` returns 'v.0.10.34'

Comment: Could there be a problem with `nohup` ... if it works running as `node ./node.js` but not `nohup ./node.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're seeing is due to the way you're trying to execute your script. `node ./node.js` works because you're explicitly loading the script via node.

However `nohup ./node.js` does not work because the shell is expecting the file to be a shell script. If you want to execute your script in this way, you'll need to add the appropriate hash bang line to tell the shell what program to use to interpret the file. For example: `#!/usr/bin/env node`

Comment: I was running `nohup node ./node.js &` originally, but apparently lost the command during the switch over.. Thanks!